# fail2ban identify the subscription specific error log which resulted in an IP ban

Tags: centos, fail2ban

I am running Fail2Ban via Parallels Plesk 12.x on several CentOS 6 containers with several active jails (*apache-noscripts*, *plesk-apache* etc.). The Fail2Ban.log provides the IP address which was banned; however, what I would like to see is which subscription the offender hit so that I can quickly open that specific subscription’s `error_log` and determine the activity associated with the banned IP address prior to the ban action. Is this possible, as it is not feasible to open 75+ error logs searching for a Banned IP address each time I would like to investigate further?

Error logs for each subscription are being checked, so it seems there should be a way to have this information displayed in the `fail2ban.log` or elsewhere.

```
fail2ban.filter [1170]: INFO Added logfile = /var/www/vhosts/system/example.com/logs/error_log
```

I have been looking for an answer to this for sometime. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question is off topic because of Plesk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fail2ban can send an email on each ban, including a whois on the IP and the relevant lines in the logs. It is possible via the *actions*.

To cite `jail.conf`:

```
# The simplest action to take: ban only
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
              %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report and relevant log lines
# to the destemail.
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s"]
```

So it's possible to automatically send an email with whois and the logs. It is also possible to trigger any other program, e.g. you can just dump this information to files.

Set the default action:

```
# Choose default action.  To change, just override value of 'action' with the
# interpolation to the chosen action shortcut (e.g.  action_mw, action_mwl, etc) in jail.local
# globally (section [DEFAULT]) or per specific section
action = %(action_mwl)s
```

Set the action per jail:

```
[ssh]
enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
action   = %(action_mwl)s
```

Then such a mail looks like: (This one is specific to postfix and shortened)

```
From: fail2ban@example.com
To: root@localhost
Subject: [Fail2Ban] postfix: banned 192.0.2.0

Hi,

The IP 192.0.2.0 has just been banned by Fail2Ban after
3 attempts against postfix.


Here are more information about 192.0.2.0:

% [whois.apnic.net]
% Whois data copyright terms    http://www.apnic.net/db/dbcopyright.html

% Information related to '192.0.2.0 - 192.0.2.255'

[... complete whois ...]

% This query was served by the APNIC Whois Service version 1.69.1-APNICv1r0 (UNDEFINED)


Lines containing IP:192.0.2.0 in /var/log/mail.log

Mar  9 04:37:05 sendai postfix/smtpd/smtpd[25172]: connect from unknown[192.0.2.0]
Mar  9 04:37:07 sendai postfix/smtpd/smtpd[25172]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[192.0.2.0]: 450 4.7.1 Client host rejected: cannot find your reverse hostname, [192.0.2.0]; from=<spammer@example.net> to=<user@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<invalid.example.com>
Mar  9 04:37:14 sendai postfix/smtpd/smtpd[25172]: disconnect from unknown[192.0.2.0]
[... and many other lines ...]


Regards,

Fail2Ban
```

You can configure your mail client or mailbox server (using sieve) to automatically delete these mails after three days and only look at them if needed.